# How to target a specific element if two blocks of element use the same nested setup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to target the second span nested inside a span to overwrite "I agree to the Rules and Regulations" so that I can hyperlink "Rules and Regulations"

```
<fieldset>
<legend class="surveyLegend Explicit">
<span class="legendWrapper" style="display:block; white-space:normal; width:100%;">
<span class="aural-only" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px;">
Question - Required -
</span>
<span>I agree to the Rules and Regulations</span>
</span> 
</legend>
<span class="NetscapeFix">
</span>
<br>
</fieldset>
```

I tried to do this:

```
$("span.aural-only").next().html("<span>I agree to the <a href="http://www.runtoquit.com/terms-conditions-p199592" target="_blank">Rules and Regulations</a></span>");
```

By targeting the span before it, I thought maybe it would work. But turns out the next question which is also a required question on the form uses the exact same layout and classes, no ids on it either.

```
<fieldset>
<legend class="surveyLegend Explicit">
<span class="legendWrapper" style="display:block; white-space:normal; width:100%;">
<span class="aural-only" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px;">
Question - Not Required -
</span>
<span>I also agree to receive email updates from:</span>
</span> 
</legend>
<span class="NetscapeFix">
</span>
<br>
</fieldset>
```

So now I'm stumped, is there any way for me to add a hyperlink to that part? The platform I'm using, Luminate Online doesn't allow hyperlinks in questions unless its a caption, which would be fine but captions don't have any yes/no or other conditionals that can be attached to it. Quite frustrating to be honest.

If anyone has a suggestion I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: `$(".legendWrapper span:nth-child(2)").html(...)`

Comment: and your string is invalid -> syntax error

Comment: In the future, please post actual code, not pictures of code. That way, we can provide working examples for you.

Comment: [Don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) ... post the actual code. Very simple to copy it from same place you took the image from

Comment: oh sorry about that, will fix.

Comment: @Jonasw sorry, could you tell me why my string is invalid so I can keep an eye out for it next time?

Comment: @umeed have a look at it again. as you see its "ab"cd"ef" , and now cd is not part of the string. so may use two different quotes e.g. "ab'cd'ef" now its one string

Comment: @Jonasw oh! I should have realized I wasn't using my quotes correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over these spans, and change their content based on their index:

```
$("span.aural-only").each(function(i){

  $(this).next().html(
   ["first content",
    "second content"
   ][i] || "error"
  );
});
```

Comment: This is brilliant! this actually saved me so much time as I'm able to change all the spans at the same time (had 5 more to do lol). Thank you so much Jonas!

Answer (score 1):

Use `:first` selector or `first()` method or `eq()`

```
$("span.aural-only").first().next().html('...')
// or
$("span.aural-only:first").next().html('...')
// or
$("span.aural-only").eq(0).next().html('...')
```

Comment: @Jonasw `eq()` uses zero based index so if it is indeed the first it is index zero

Comment: @Jonasw not according to ... *"but the next question contains.."*

Answer (score 0):

I'd change your selector to use an adjacent sibling combinator and :contains, like:

```js
$('.aural-only + span:contains("I agree to the Rules and Regulations")').html('<span>I agree to the <a href="http://www.runtoquit.com/terms-conditions-p199592" target="_blank">Rules and Regulations</a></span>');
```